# Highcharts zIndex issue with crosshair

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle, highcharts

I have recently (since yesterday) started using highcharts. I am using an `area` plot for the series. I have enabled the the cross-hair and set its `zIndex` larger such that it is visible above the plot area. But, another problem arose here. The marker (I used a circle here), is behind the cross-hair. I mean the sequence now is (plot->marker->cross-hair).

Now, what I want is (plot->cross-hair->marker). Is this even possible at all? If yes, what all do I have to do?

Below is a image scenario of the situation at hand. Please do correct me, if I am wrong anywhere.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is set the crosshairs

```
tooltip: {
  crosshairs: [true, true]
}
```

and marker width

```
plotOptions: {
  area: {
    marker: {
      enabled: false,
      symbol: 'circle',
      radius: 6,
      states: {
        hover: {
          enabled: true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work. CrossHair is still above the marker

Comment: Hey, good to know! This worked back when the question was asked, in early 2012. Highcharts is updated quite frequently - maybe things have changed.

Comment: seems like yes :) so now I need more modern solution :)